# Is there a general procedure to apply the regularity theorem for tempered distributions?

Tags: schwartz-distributions

The regularity theorem for tempered distributions states that a tempered distribution is some weak derivative of a polynomially bounded continuous function.

For example, the delta function $\delta(x)$ in one dimensions is the second order weak-derivative of $g(x)=x \cdot \chi_{[0,\infty)}$.

I wonder if there is a general procedure for finding such a continuous function and the weak derivatives for any given tempered distribution.

In fact, I am particularly stuck at the case of
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta\Bigl(x_1- \sqrt{x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2}\Bigr)}{\sqrt{x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2}}
\end{equation}
as a tempered distribution on $\mathbb{R}^4$. Here $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ are the Cartesian coordinates. How can one find a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^4$ and weak derivatives that characterize this distribution?

Could anyone please provide any information?

Comment: For $f\in S(\Bbb{R}^n)$ let 
 $F_j(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x_j} f(x+e_j t)dt, B_j[f](x)=F_j(x)-erf(x_j)F_j(x+\infty e_j)$. For $T\in S'(\Bbb{R}^n)$ let $\langle C_j[T],f\rangle= \langle T,B_j[f]\rangle$. Then $\partial_{x_j} C_j[T] = -T$. It remains to show that tempered distributions have finite order and that applying $C_1\ldots C_n$ decreases the order.

Comment: I do not understand your notations. What exactly is $B_j$? What do you mean by $er$? Could you explain more in detail?

Comment: @reuns: would be good to elaborate and turn comment into answer.

Comment: $erf$ primitive of Gaussian. $B_j[\partial_{x_j} f]=f$.

Comment: When restricting to $\phi \in C^\infty_c(|x|<r)$ a distribution is bounded in the $\sum_{|\alpha|\le k} \|\partial^\alpha\phi\|_\infty$ norm for some $k$. For tempered distributions there is some $k$ independent of $r$, the least of which is the order of the distribution.